# NGRX Find a one object form list and update it

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a list of objects in my `ngrx/store` when the user clicks on the button I want to find that object using object id and update it the relevant properties withour `ngxr/entities`.somehow I manage to do that but I know that's, not the correct way.this my current implementation.

```
const initialState: TourListState = {
    tours: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
}

const tourListReducer = createReducer(initialState,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    on(createTourListSucess, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isLoading: false }
    }),
    on(updateTourList, (state, { tour }) => {
      state.tours.find(tourex => tourex.tourId === tour.tourId).coverImage = tour.coverImage;
      state.tours.find(tourex => tourex.tourId === tour.tourId).title = tour.title;
      state.tours.find(tourex => tourex.tourId === tour.tourId).priceInfo = tour.priceInfo;
      state.tours.find(tourex => tourex.tourId === tour.tourId).city = tour.city;
      state.tours.find(tourex => tourex.tourId === tour.tourId).countryName = tour.countryName;
      return { ...state, isLoading: false }
    }),
    on(updateTourListSuccess, (state) => {
        return { ...state, isLoading: false }
    }),
    ....,
)

export function reducer(state: TourListState | undefined, action: Action) {
    return tourListReducer(state, action)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're directly modifying state, which is not recommended - even if you clone it afterwards.

You can use the map operator in your case:

```
return {
   ...state,
   tours: state.tours.map(t => t.tourId === tourId ? (updateTour) : t) 
}
```

The above snippets loops through the tours collection, if it finds the tour to be updated it will update it, otherwise it will just return the tour as is.

Another solution would be to use [`mutableOn`](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc#mutableon) (which uses Immer underneath).

```
mutableOn(update, (state, { tour }) => {
    const entity = state.tours.find(t => t.tourId === tourId)
    if (entity) {
      entity.foo = tour.foo
      entity.bar = tour.bar
    }
  }),
```

Comment: "You're directly modifying state, which is not recommended - even if you clone it afterwards." thats why I mention that above I know something is wrong so I want to what is the best way for this.if implement it using this map operator is it correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want to modify an array that's the way I know